# Defining a Complex Sort (by stripping out a pre-defined set of words) with Views

Tags: views

I'd like to do a more complex sorting on my Drupal 7 View. Specifically, I'd like to sort by a particular field alphabetically (easy - that's the default). **However, before the View sorts the field I want it to strip out (a predefined) set of words at the beginning of the field (if they exist) such as the word 'the' or 'a' and sort based on the words that follow**.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

My workaround will be to just create a 'sort by' field in the content type.

Comment: +1 Good question. It can be done in MySQL using temporary column at query time: [MySQL Sort Alphabetically but Ignore “The”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087603/mysql-sort-alphabetically-but-ignore-the). Interesting to see if there will be a good answer to this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it's a good idea. I'll try the given answer first and if that doesn't meet our needs this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [Views Natural Sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_natural_sort) -module?

> Provides a views filter that sorts node titles by a more natural manner by ignoring articles like "The" and "A."

Not sure if it matches your needs because of *"sorts node titles"* and in your question you talk about particular field. But maybe you should try it?

At least you can get base for custom module if you need to build one.

Comment: +1 This post explains how to enable natural sort for fields: [How to use Views Natural Sort 2.0](http://generalredneck.com/blog/how-use-views-natural-sort-20)

Comment: Love this - looks like it will almost perfectly meet our needs.